# adding and removing a node from a mongo replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I have a new backup server I want to add to our mongo replica sets. As far as I can tell its as easy as logging on to the replica sets primary and adding the following command:

`rs.add( { host: "mongobackup:10003", priority: 0, votes: 0, hidden: true } )`

My understanding is that after doing so the primary should sync all its configuration and data with the new node.

Additionally I have an old backup server I want to remove from the replica set which I looks like all i have to do is type this command into the replica sets primary:

`rs.remove( "oldmongobackup:10003" )`

Is there anything else I am missing?

```
rs2:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs2",
    "version" : 26,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 7,
            "host" : "mongo03:10001",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 20,
            "tags" : {
                "dc" : "maid"
            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "host" : "mongo01:10002",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 10,
            "tags" : {
                "dc" : "maid"
            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "host" : "mongo02:10003",
            "arbiterOnly" : true,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 10,
            "host" : "oldmongobackup:10003",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : true,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post `rs.conf()` in the question

Comment: Hi, this has been updated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command should be fine to run. Why ???

Each `rs.add()` and `rs.remove()` should trigger an election. Since the priorities of the remaining nodes have unique values:

- `_id : 7` as `priority : 20`
- `_id : 8` as `priority : 10`
- `_id : 9` as `priority : 1`

you can say the election is rigged. The primary node should remain the primary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, turns out it was as simple as rs.add() and rs.remove(). I have now added the new back up server as a node to all 3 of my replica sets and removed the old server from each replica set. happy days! :)  I guess I was worried there was more to it than just that.

Comment: You should always check `rs.conf()` anyway. If the priorities were just zeros and ones, an election could possibly freeze the cluster. Since one node is an arbiter, the election of a PRIMARY could be decided properly in this case. Hey, better safe than sorry. Thank you for accepting this answer.